# Singular values of difference of two matrices in specific setting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have the SVD $X = U\Sigma V^T$, where we can assume $\Sigma$ is nonzero. Suppose we have a matrix $G$ satisfying 
$$Tr(X^TG) = Tr(\Sigma)$$
$$\sigma_1(G) \leq 1$$
where $\sigma_1(G)$ is its largest singular value. I am trying to prove that then 
$$\sigma_1(G - UV^T) \leq 1$$
Both conditions must be necessary, because otherwise we could take $G = -UV^T$ and get a counterexample. The first condition says that 
$$Tr(V\Sigma U^TG) = Tr(\Sigma) \implies Tr((U^TGV - I)\Sigma) = 0$$
This doesn't quite say $G = UV^T$ (if it did, the problem would be trivial), but I'm thinking it might say something close enough so that we can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma$ needs to be full rank, otherwise, Wolog let $\Sigma_{00}=0$, entries of $G'=U^TGV$ be all $0$ except $G'_{00}=-0.99$, all conditions are satisfied and  $\sigma_1(G-UV^T)=1.99$.

If $\Sigma$ is full rank, because $x^T(I-G')x\geq 0$ for any vector $x$, the diagonal terms of $I-G'$ must be non-negative, hence all zero. Hence, the diagonal terms of $G'$ must be all $1$. Because $\sigma_1(G')\leq 1$, $G'$ must be diagonal. Hence, $I-G'=0$.

Comment: I don't understand your last line. How do we know $I - G'$ is PSD, and how can we then conclude it's zero?

Comment: @lmnop Oops, I just realized I shouldn't have used the term PSD, because G' needs to be proved to be symmetric before that. I've updated my answer.